# Display specific Google Map info window on load

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I've put together a simple multi-marker map using some the Google Maps examples. The code is as follows:

```
function initMap() {

  var center = {
    lat: 51.7504111,
    lng: -1.2826071
  };

  var locations = [
    ['Philz Coffee<br>\
    801 S Hope St A, Los Angeles, CA 90017<br>\
    <a href="https://goo.gl/maps/L8ETMBt7cRA2">Get Directions</a>', 34.046438, -118.259653],
    ['Philz Coffee<br>\
    525 Santa Monica Blvd, Santa Monica, CA 90401<br>\
    <a href="https://goo.gl/maps/PY1abQhuW9C2">Get Directions</a>', 34.017951, -118.493567],
    ['Philz Coffee<br>\
    146 South Lake Avenue #106, At Shoppers Lane, Pasadena, CA 91101<br>\
    <a href="https://goo.gl/maps/eUmyNuMyYNN2">Get Directions</a>', 34.143073, -118.132040],
    ['Philz Coffee<br>\
    21016 Pacific Coast Hwy, Huntington Beach, CA 92648<br>\
    <a href="https://goo.gl/maps/Cp2TZoeGCXw">Get Directions</a>', 33.655199, -117.998640],
    ['Philz Coffee<br>\
    252 S Brand Blvd, Glendale, CA 91204<br>\
    <a href="https://goo.gl/maps/WDr2ef3ccVz">Get Directions</a>', 34.142823, -118.254569]
  ];

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 9,
    center: center
  });

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});
  var marker, count;

  for (count = 0; count < locations.length; count++) {

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[count][1], locations[count][2]),
      map: map,
      title: locations[count][0]
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, count) {
      return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(locations[count][0]);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }
    })(marker, count));
  }
}

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  infowindow.open(map, marker);
});

infowindow.open(map, marker);
```

I added the following to try and make the info windows display by default (the docs suggest this should work), but this doesn't appear to work:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  infowindow.open(map, marker);
});

infowindow.open(map, marker);
```

But what I'm really trying to achieve is how to display a specific marker on page load, for example the second 'Philz Coffee' location. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Inside your for loop, but at its end, try adding `if (count == 1) infowindow.open(map,marker);`

Comment: Strangely, that results in a tiny infowindow, but with no content. Removing the line brings back the content but only onClick.

Comment: Right; there's only a single `infowindow` and it appears when a marker is clicked. Do this: 1. store the marker inside the loop in a variable: `if (count == 1) initialMarker = marker;` 2. after the loop, call `google.maps.event.trigger(initialMarker, 'click');`

Comment: `marker` is undefined where you are trying to register the click event. Btw. if you are registering a click event listener, the infowindow won't open "by default" as you specified. You should use `infowindow.open(map, marker);` without the event listener, on **one** specific marker.

Comment: Thanks, Chris. This seems to work. I've actually structured it a little differently as I'm getting some data from PHP, but the concept is the same. Please put this as the answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One (good) way to achieve this is to define your "default" Marker and trigger a click event on it (since you have already registered a click event on each Marker).

Working snippet below. Code is commented so it should speak for itself.

```js
function initialize() {

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 5,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(1, 1)
    };

    var locations = [
        [new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0), 'Marker 1', 'Infowindow content for Marker 1'],
        [new google.maps.LatLng(0, 1), 'Marker 2', 'Infowindow content for Marker 2'],
        [new google.maps.LatLng(0, 2), 'Marker 3', 'Infowindow content for Marker 3'],
        [new google.maps.LatLng(1, 0), 'Marker 4', 'Infowindow content for Marker 4'],
        [new google.maps.LatLng(1, 1), 'Marker 5', 'Infowindow content for Marker 5'],
        [new google.maps.LatLng(1, 2), 'Marker 6', 'Infowindow content for Marker 6']
    ];

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    
    // Create empty markers array
    var markers = [];

    // Create empty Info Window
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    // Create marker for each location
    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: locations[i][0],
            map: map,
            title: locations[i][1]
        });

        // Register click event on each marker
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {

            return function () {
                infowindow.setContent(locations[i][2]);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }

        })(marker, i));
        
        // Push marker to markers array
        markers.push(marker);
    }
    
    // Define the default marker, here for example the marker labeled "Marker 4"
    var defaultMarker = markers[3];
    
    // Trigger click on default marker
    google.maps.event.trigger(defaultMarker, 'click');
}
```

```css
#map-canvas {
  height: 180px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map-canvas"></div>

<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initialize" async defer></script>
```

Comment: This looks like a very elegant way - great solution! thanks.